# Trying to get the key of something passed as a parameter

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to simplify one of my existing script by combining everthing to one general function. The new function look like this :

```
function orderRibbons($ribbon_first) {
    $nameOfBody = ________;
}

orderRibbons($ribbons['Eve']);
```

How would I extract the key (In this case, "Eve") from the parameter and assign it to a variable?

This is what the array look like :

```
Array ( [Eve] => Array ( [s] => 1 [o] => 0 [eo] => 0 [po] => 0 ) 
        [Gilly] => Array ( [s] => 1 [o] => 0 [eo] => 0 [po] => 0 )
        ...
      )
```

Thank you, Moustachauve

Comment: Why can't you just pass the key in instead of the value?

Comment: you can use array_keys() to extract the keys of the array (http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php)

Comment: Austin, I can't just pass the key, because I need what is inside the array I am passing. Also, I can't modify the structure of the array, as I am updating a script.

Alon, using array_keys() only return me keys inside the second dimension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the function this way:

```
function orderRibbons($arrRibbon, $keyRibbon) {
    $nameOfBody = $keyRibbon;
}
```

Then call it using:

```
orderRibbons($ribbons,'Eve')
```

Comment: Would I gain any advantage or disadvantage from passing it in an array, like this :

orderRibbons(array('Eve', $ribbons['Eve']));

Comment: I don't see any advantages to that. The disadvantage is that you still only have part of the full array to manipulate inside the function.

Comment: Oh, never mind, I didn't red your answer correctly the first time. The way you do it would be the best for me, thank you

Comment: Why is the `$keyRibbon` value copied?

Answer (score 2):

If you call a function like this:

```
orderRibbons($ribbons['Eve']);
```

you do not know the array key inside that function. You CAN'T know it, because the value that gets passed into the function is the value of `$ribbons['Eve']`, which does not include the key for that array. The value of `$ribbon_first` is `Array ( [s] => 1 [o] => 0 [eo] => 0 [po] => 0 )`.

Comment: So I should pass the name as a second parameter?

Comment: I don't know what you want to achieve. If the key name is of any use, then pass it.

Comment: Thank you, the key name is exactly what I was trying to use, and I hopped there was a way to get it without passing it, but you just confirmed me I couldn't.